# Error: "TALLYING clause is incomplete", how to fix it?

Tags: cobol

My program

```
      ******************************************************************
      * Author:
      * Date:
      * Purpose:
      * Tectonics: cobc
      ******************************************************************
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
       
       DATA DIVISION.       
           WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
           01 WS-CNT1 PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.
           01 WS-CNT2 PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.
           01 WS-STRING PIC X(15) VALUE 'ABCDACDADEAAAFF'.
       
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           INSPECT WS-STRING TALLYING WS-CNT1 FOR CHARACTER.
           DISPLAY "WS-CNT1 : "WS-CNT1.
           INSPECT WS-STRING TALLYING WS-CNT2 FOR ALL 'A'.
           DISPLAY "WS-CNT2 : "WS-CNT2       
           STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```

Error: "TALLYING clause is incomplete" and "syntax error, unexpected CHARACTER.", how to fix it?

Comment: Screenshot https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/171115928-2d802e45-3761-414e-b0c7-e77b0a269ac3.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is `INSPECT identifier-1 TALLYING identifier-2 FOR CHARACTERS`, you've missed the "S".